# Fill string.xml file from webService

Tags: android, web-services

I just have a little question about Android developpement.

The question is : Can I fill the string.xml from a response of a webService. If it's possible how can I do this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: no you can't using the system localization mechanism. You have to provide your own

Answer (score 1):

> Can I fill the string.xml from a response of a webService.

No.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I fill the string.xml from a response of a webService?

No, string.xml is an immutable file into your apk.
But you can add a proxy between your views and the resources to be used.
`Philology` does it for you, you can check the library on Github:
https://github.com/jcminarro/Philology